# Making Excel VBA code work for all rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have created the statement below which which works just as I need it to with one flaw, it only works on the second row of my sheet (the first contains a header row).

How can I make it work for all rows within the sheet? The sheet has a varying number of rows in it from day to day.

```
Dim result As String
Adnet = Range("AB2").Value
TSNumber = Range("BQ2").Value

If (Adnet = "goog" Or Adnet = "bing" Or TSNumber = "8006522096" Or TSNumber = "8006522097" Or TSNumber = "8006522098") Then
    result = "PPC"
Else
    result = "None/Other"
End If

Range("AC2").Value = result
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the first line of the sub look like?

Comment: Sub MI_Subchannel()

'
' MI_Subchannel
'

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim result As String, N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        Adnet = Range("AB" & i).Value
        TSNumber = Range("BQ" & i).Value
        If (Adnet = "goog" Or Adnet = "bing" Or TSNumber = "8006522096" Or TSNumber = "8006522097" Or TSNumber = "8006522098") Then
            result = "PPC"
        Else
            result = "None/Other"
        End If
        Range("AC" & i).Value = result
    Next i
End Sub
```